# Understanding the elements of a VBA statement

Tags: vba, excel

I've been recently given an Excel worksheet with VBA coded into it. Currently I am studying it to try and understand how it works. However, I stumbled upon a function called 'runv'.

```
pdate = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ALLOCATION").Cells(runv + 6,5), 6)
```

Until today, I still can't figure out what 'runv' is and what it's function is. I even tried searching online and all I found are results autocorrected as 'run'. Does anyone knows what it means?

Comment: `runv` should be a variable here containing a number. `runv + 6` makes for a row index.

Comment: It looks like a variable. Don't you have `runv =` somewhere before this line?

Comment: never mind. I see it. runv = 3. my bad... Now what I don't understand is the 6 at the end. What does it do? I simulate it and can't find anything...

Comment: It is finding the value in cell (9,5) on the "Allocation" sheet, converting it to text (implicitly), and assigning the first 6 letters of that text to the variable "pdate".

Comment: Generally speaking, objects, functions, properties that come from VBA will be written in CamelCase (like `ActiveWorkbook`). That means, if something starts with lower case, it's 100% sure it 's user defined. That means also, if you want to use VBA function and it doesn't change to CamelCase after hitting Enter at the end, you did something wrong. **Edit:** there are some VBA objects that are written in camelCase, like `xlDown`.

Answer (score 1):

The 6 at the end is the second parameter of the Left() function, which specifies how many characters are extracted from the string in the first parameter, starting from the left. The syntax for Left() is

```
=LEFT(string, howManyCharactersToExtract)
```